# Select and plot nightly hours between two days in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I want to plot the number of individuals detected during the night, between 18h and 6h. I cannot find a solution to represent this on a single graph, taking the hours 18-00h of day 1 and 00-6h of day 2. Any ideas?

I have this type of data (simplified) :

```
year    site    id  date    hour
2018    A   1   24/07/2018  01:58:50
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  20:44:44
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  04:07:56
2018    A   1   25/07/2018  03:46:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  20:04:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  03:51:40
2018    A   1   26/07/2018  03:29:07
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  20:08:24
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  03:05:07
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  19:56:40
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  03:38:09
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  20:08:53
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  03:27:47
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  19:59:34
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  03:54:58
2018    A   2   28/07/2018  20:11:35
```

I plotted this with this example data :

[image]

And I would like with something like this :

[image]

And this is my code :

```
df <- read.table(text = "year    site    id  date    hour
2018    A   1   24/07/2018  01:58:50
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  20:44:44
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  04:07:56
2018    A   1   25/07/2018  03:46:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  20:04:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  03:51:40
2018    A   1   26/07/2018  03:29:07
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  20:08:24
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  03:05:07
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  19:56:40
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  03:38:09
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  20:08:53
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  03:27:47
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  19:59:34
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  03:54:58
2018    A   2   28/07/2018  20:11:35", header = TRUE)


df$DATETIME <- lubridate::dmy_hms(paste(df$date, df$hour))

list_comm <- split(df, df$site) # split for each site

bar_plots <- lapply(list_comm, function(x){

  #x <- list_comm[[1]]

  tab <- x %>%
    mutate(HOUR = as.numeric(strftime(DATETIME, format = "%H"))) %>%
    group_by(hour, date, year) %>%
    summarise(count = as.numeric(length(id))) %>%
    select(hour, date, year, count)

  tab %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = count, fill = count))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 3,4,5, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23),
                       labels=c("00:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "12:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"),
                       limits=c(0,24)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red") +
    facet_wrap(date~. , ncol =1, scales="free_x") +
    labs(x = "Hour", y = "Number of passage", title = paste(unique(x$site), "-", unique(x$year))) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0, face="bold")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
    theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 8)) 

  ggsave(paste("results/04_movement_pattern/new_marked_individuals/barplot_pheno/2018-",unique(x$site),"panel_pheno_summer_sites.png"), width = 10, height=10, units = "in") #Save plot

} 
)

print(bar_plots)
```

No matter how hard I look for a solution, I can't find it and lost about. I welcome any suggestion. thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hey @maryvrx, if you could use something like ```dput(head(df, 10))``` and paste here the output it will make a sample of your dataset reproducible for others and more people will help this way. Or just ```dput(df)``` if your dataset is not too long.

Comment: Hey @Yach thanks for that remark. I have a very long dataset, but I will try to edit my question to make it more reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it, the problem is that you messed up your hour variables. I guess you planned to map your continuous `HOUR` variable on the x-axis. Instead you are trying to plot the categorical character variable `hour` on a continuous scale which will not work. To add `HOUR` to your `tab` I included it in the `group_by` and the `select` statements. Also to get the kind of plot I added a transformation of `HOUR`. Try this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "year    site    id  date    hour
2018    A   1   24/07/2018  01:58:50
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  20:44:44
2018    A   2   24/07/2018  04:07:56
2018    A   1   25/07/2018  03:46:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  20:04:11
2018    A   2   25/07/2018  03:51:40
2018    A   1   26/07/2018  03:29:07
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  20:08:24
2018    A   2   26/07/2018  03:05:07
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  19:56:40
2018    A   1   27/07/2018  03:38:09
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  20:08:53
2018    A   2   27/07/2018  03:27:47
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  19:59:34
2018    A   1   28/07/2018  03:54:58
2018    A   2   28/07/2018  20:11:35", header = TRUE)

df$DATETIME <- lubridate::dmy_hms(paste(df$date, df$hour))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

list_comm <- split(df, df$site) # split for each site

bar_plots <- lapply(list_comm, function(x){

  x <- list_comm[[1]]

  tab <- x %>%
    mutate(HOUR = lubridate::hour(DATETIME)) %>%
    group_by(hour, date, year, HOUR) %>%
    summarise(count = as.numeric(length(id))) %>%
    select(hour, date, year, count, HOUR) %>% 
    mutate(HOUR1 = ifelse(HOUR >= 19 & HOUR <= 24, HOUR - 19, HOUR + 6))

  tab %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = HOUR1, y = count, fill = count))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:10,
                       labels=c("19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00"),
                       limits=c(0, 10)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red") +
    facet_wrap(date~. , ncol =1, scales="free_x") +
    labs(x = "Hour", y = "Number of passage", title = paste(unique(x$site), "-", unique(x$year))) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0, face="bold")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
    theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 8)) 

} 
)
bar_plots$A
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey @stefan, actually, I forgot to put this in my df simplified but I have this variable (of the same name DATETIME). But even with that I can't seem to find a way to represent the counts between 6 p.m. and 6 a.m.

Comment: @maryvrx I added `DATETIME` via `df$DATETIME <- lubridate::dmy_hms(paste(df$date, df$hour))`. How did you create DATETIME? What type ist it? Perhaps something went wrong with the conversion? Simply add the code to create DATETIME to your post or as a comment.

Comment: I used POSIXct to create my DATETIME variable : ```df$DATETIME <- paste(df$DATE, df$HEURE, " ")``` and after ```df$DATETIME <- as.POSIXct(df$DATETIME, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") # change date format```

Comment: I corrected this error in my code and updated my first post

Comment: @maryvrx Tricky one. (; First. For the conversion to `HOUR` is simply use `lubridate::hours`. At least on my machine using your conversion resulted in a time shift by 2 hours. Next. To get the kind of plot I apply a transformation to `HOUR`. Don't know whether there is simpler wy, e.g. using date axis. And perhaps not perfect. But at least to me, it looks like the plot you tried to achieve.

Comment: Sometimes I don't help myself x). Yes I will continue my exploration to try to find a solution to plot this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @maryvrx Hm. Just of curiosity. What's wrong with the "solution" I posted?

Comment: As you can see with the second plot of my post, I want to plot counts of individuals between 6pm and 6am, during all the night is the same plot. The challenge is about plot two days in the same plot to have all night activity. Did you understand what i would like to do ?

Comment: Okay. Got it. Transform the date. As you facet on date you have to do something like this: `date = lubridate::dmy(date) - lubridate::days(if_else(HOUR >= 12, 0, 1))`, i.e. for hours between 0 to 12 you set the date to yesterday. This way you group hours 12 to 24 from today with hours 0 to 12 from tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan, you solve my problem :D. I add the solution in my post.

Comment: You are welcome @maryvrx. Was a tricky one. But one of the problems I like as I learned a lot by checking out how to solve it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the precious help of @stefan

```
bar_plots <- lapply(list_comm, function(x){

  x <- list_comm[[1]]

  tab <- x %>%
    mutate(HOUR = lubridate::hour(DATETIME)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    slice(which(!(date == x$date[1] & HOUR < 19))) %>% #remove morning hour of the first day of capture 
    group_by(hour, date, year, HOUR) %>%
    summarise(count = as.numeric(length(id))) %>%
    select(hour, date, year, count, HOUR) %>% 
    mutate(HOUR1 = ifelse(HOUR >= 19 & HOUR <= 24, HOUR - 19, HOUR + 6)) %>% #to inverse the x axis 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date) - lubridate::days(if_else(HOUR >= 12, 0, 1))) #for hours between 0 to 12 you set the date to yesterday. This way you group hours 12 to 24 from today with hours 0 to 12 from tomorrow

  #Pass to english format to plot  
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

 tab %>%
   mutate(date = paste(lubridate::day(date), "to", lubridate::day(lubridate::date(tab$date)+1), lubridate::month(date, label=TRUE, abbr = FALSE),lubridate::year(date))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = HOUR1, y = count, fill = count))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:10,
                       labels=c("19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00"),
                       limits=c(0, 10)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red") +
    facet_wrap(date~. , ncol =1, scales="free_x") +
    labs(x = "Hour", y = "Number of passage", title = paste(unique(x$site), "-", unique(x$year))) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0, face="bold")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
    theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 8)) 

} 
)
bar_plots$A
```

That products :

[image]

Very useful for my analyzes of nocturnal activities :)